# How to manipulate expect out buffer

Tags: tcl, expect

I have written an application in Tcl-Expect which spawns minicom and
sends and receives data via the serial port. Sometimes i see that the
application receives control characters along with human readable data.
A search on the internet tells me that the control characters are
nothing but the VT terminal codes. However i could not find a solution
to filter out the terminal codes.

I am attaching a sample of the expected buffer and the actual buffer.

Expected :-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200](c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\Windows\system32>
```

Actual:-

```
[1;1H[37m[40m [2;1H [3;1H [4;1H [5;1H [6;1H [7;1H [8;1H [9;1H [10;1H [11;1H [12;1H [13;1H [14;1H [15;1H [16;1H [17;1H [18;1H [19;1H [20;1H [21;1H [22;1H [23;1H [24;1H [1;1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200][2;1H(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[4;1HC:Windowssystem32>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *want* to filter them out when doing the initial match; they're useful for ensuring that you get exactly what you want (a prompt/banner). But when you're extracting the sense, you most certainly *do* want to filter them out first. Luckily, it's fairly easy with `regsub` magic:

```
regsub -all {\u00AB\[[\d;]*[A-Za-z]} $expect_out(buffer) "" filtered
```

That replaces all escape sequences (ESC (`\u00AB`) followed by a bracket, any number of digits and semicolons, and a letter) in the Expect match buffer (pick something else if you have a better candidate) with the empty string, and then stores the result in the `filtered` variable.